# repeating-linear-gradient suddenly cuts under the fold

Tags: html, css

On [my site](http://slicedbread.xyz), I'm having issues with the `repeating-linear-gradient`element in CSS. For the majority of the page, the background looks ok. But suddenly, when I scroll down, it looks as if the gradient just shifts one bar to the right and makes my page look ugly. This is what I currently have as CSS:

```
    background:repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,transparent,transparent 50px,rgba(255,255,255,.1) 50px,rgba(255,255,255,.1)100px), #81D4FA;
```

I'm really having trouble, and it would be great if someone could help me. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe `background-attachment: fixed;` on `body` will help you.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: `:)` glad i could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, `background-attachment: fixed;` will prevent the seam from being visible, but the stripes do not scroll with the page.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient):

> A repeating CSS linear gradient is not a CSS `<color>` but an image with
>   no intrinsic dimensions; that is, it has no natural or preferred size,
>   nor ratio. Its concrete size will match the one of the element it
>   applies to.

This means that the positioning of the edge of the image depends on the size of the element, and a 45deg line will not line up with its neighbors unless one of the dimensions is a multiple of the other. I recommend making a tile-able image in your image editor of choice and loading it as an asset rather than using `repeating-linear-gradient()` if you don't want the background to be fixed in place.